# problems getting ThreadedTCPServer to work with selenium and report-portal

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, reportportal

I've encountered a behavior that I simply do not understand.
Implementing a ThreadedTCPServer with selenium was working fine until I decided to attach reportportal...

For the sake of simplicity - I've tried to boil down the code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the issue:

```
import http.server
import socketserver
from typing import Optional
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver


class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass


def title_extractor(
    headless: bool = True
):
    import concurrent.futures

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        host, port = "localhost", 8050

        with ThreadedTCPServer((host, port), http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) as server:
            print(f"serving at port {port}")

            # Start a thread for the server
            print('Starting server ...')
            executor.submit(server.serve_forever)
            # Start a thread for selenium
            print('Starting page_worker ...')
            future_nonce = executor.submit(page_worker, None, headless)
            print('... page_worker done')

            done_set, not_done_set = concurrent.futures.wait(
                [future_nonce],
                timeout=300,
                return_when=concurrent.futures.ALL_COMPLETED
            )
            for future in done_set:
                if future.done():
                    print('encountered future.done()')
                    pass
                if future.cancelled():
                    print('encountered future.cancelled()')
                    pass
                if future.exception(timeout=3):
                    print(f'encountered future.exception(): {str(future.exception())}')
                    result = None
                    continue
                    # raise RuntimeError(str(future.exception()))

                print(f'future: {str(future)}')
                result = future.result(timeout=3)
                print('... future result finished')
                print(f"Result:\t{result}")

            print('Shutting down server ...')
            server.shutdown()
            executor.shutdown(wait=False)
            print('... server and executor shut down')

            return result


def page_worker(
    driver: Optional[WebDriver] = None,
    headless: bool = True
) -> Optional[str]:
    import selenium
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    terminate_driver = False

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    if headless:
        options.add_argument("--headless")

    # Start a new driver and stop it afterwards at the end of the worker call
    if driver is None:
        terminate_driver = True
        url = "https://google.com"
        print(f"Starting chrome driver with URL={url}\n"
              f"headless={headless}\toptions={str(options)}")
        driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        print(f"driver={driver}")

    title = driver.title

    if terminate_driver:
        print("Stopping driver")
        driver.quit()

    print(f"Worker terminating")

    return title


def test__page_worker_with_report_portal():
    title = title_extractor(headless=True)
    print(f"Worker finished. Page title: {title}")
```

---

Here's the call (without reportportal integration) that works:

`python3 -m pytest --show-capture=all -s -v ./Tests/Debugging/NonceWithRP.py`

Here's the result:

```
(venv) bartoszc@bartoszclnx:~/PycharmProjects/ryd-tests$ python3 -m pytest --show-capture=all -s -v ./Tests/Debugging/NonceWithRP.py
MARKERS: {''}
======================================================= test session starts =======================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-7.1.1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- .../venv/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: ..., configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: allure-pytest-2.9.45, reportportal-5.1.0, repeat-0.9.1
collected 1 item                                                                                                                  

Tests/Debugging/NonceWithRP.py::test__page_worker_with_report_portal serving at port 8050
Starting server ...
Starting page_worker ...
Starting chrome driver with URL=https://google.com
headless=True   options=<selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options object at 0x7fa3149e8eb0>... page_worker done


---------------------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG 17:38:10: POST http://localhost:58501/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "chrome", "pageLoadStrategy": "normal", "goog:chromeOptions": {"extensions": [], "args": ["--no-sandbox", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--headless"]}}}, "desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "chrome", "pageLoadStrategy": "normal", "goog:chromeOptions": {"extensions": [], "args": ["--no-sandbox", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--headless"]}}}
DEBUG 17:38:10: Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:58501
DEBUG 17:38:10: http://localhost:58501 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 200 752
DEBUG 17:38:10: Finished Request
DEBUG 17:38:10: POST http://localhost:58501/session/cbf04df70cb13b87b74624492c5682ae/url {"url": "https://google.com"}
DEBUG 17:38:11: http://localhost:58501 "POST /session/cbf04df70cb13b87b74624492c5682ae/url HTTP/1.1" 200 14
DEBUG 17:38:11: Finished Request
driver=<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="cbf04df70cb13b87b74624492c5682ae")>
DEBUG 17:38:11: GET http://localhost:58501/session/cbf04df70cb13b87b74624492c5682ae/title {}
DEBUG 17:38:11: http://localhost:58501 "GET /session/cbf04df70cb13b87b74624492c5682ae/title HTTP/1.1" 200 18
DEBUG 17:38:11: Finished Request
Stopping driver
DEBUG 17:38:11: DELETE http://localhost:58501/session/cbf04df70cb13b87b74624492c5682ae {}
DEBUG 17:38:11: http://localhost:58501 "DELETE /session/cbf04df70cb13b87b74624492c5682ae HTTP/1.1" 200 14
DEBUG 17:38:11: Finished Request
Worker terminating
encountered future.done()
future: <Future at 0x7fa314b0e340 state=finished returned str>
... future result finished
Result: Google
Shutting down server ...
... server and executor shut down
Worker finished. Page title: Google
PASSED
```

---

Here's the call with reportportal integration, where it breaks:

`python3 -m pytest --reportportal --show-capture=all -s -v ./Tests/Debugging/NonceWithRP.py`

Here's the result:

```
MARKERS: {''}

------------------------------------------------------ live log sessionstart ------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG 17:41:37: ReportPortal - Init service: endpoint=...
DEBUG 17:41:37: Starting new HTTP connection (1): ...
DEBUG 17:41:37: ... "GET /api/v1/testchuck/settings HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG 17:41:37: ReportPortal - Start launch: request_body=...
DEBUG 17:41:37: ... "POST /api/v2/testchuck/launch HTTP/1.1" 201 None
DEBUG 17:41:37: start_launch - ID: ...
DEBUG 17:41:37: ReportPortal - Launch started: id=...
DEBUG 17:41:37: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.google-analytics.com:443
DEBUG 17:41:38: https://www.google-analytics.com:443 "POST /collect HTTP/1.1" 200 35
======================================================= test session starts =======================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-7.1.1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- .../venv/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: ..., configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: allure-pytest-2.9.45, reportportal-5.1.0, repeat-0.9.1
collected 1 item                                                                                                                  
------------------------------------------------------- live log collection -------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG 17:41:38: ReportPortal - Start TestItem: request_body={'attributes': [], 'name': 'Tests/Debugging/NonceWithRP.py::test__page_worker_with_report_portal', 'description': None, 'start_time': '1650555698079', 'item_type': 'STEP', 'code_ref': 'Tests/Debugging/NonceWithRP.py:test__page_worker_with_report_portal', 'parameters': None, 'parent_item_id': None, 'test_case_id': 'Tests/Debugging/NonceWithRP.py:test__page_worker_with_report_portal'}
DEBUG 17:41:38: ... "POST /api/v2/testchuck/item HTTP/1.1" 201 None
DEBUG 17:41:38: start_test_item - ID: ...

Tests/Debugging/NonceWithRP.py::test__page_worker_with_report_portal serving at port 8050
Starting server ...
Starting page_worker ...
Starting chrome driver with URL=https://google.com
headless=True   options=<selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options object at 0x7fcac84b5370>
... page_worker done

---------------------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG 17:41:38: POST http://localhost:56813/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "chrome", "pageLoadStrategy": "normal", "goog:chromeOptions": {"extensions": [], "args": ["--no-sandbox", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--headless"]}}}, "desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "chrome", "pageLoadStrategy": "normal", "goog:chromeOptions": {"extensions": [], "args": ["--no-sandbox", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--headless"]}}}
encountered future.done()
encountered future.exception(): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'log'
Shutting down server ...
... server and executor shut down
Worker finished. Page title: None
PASSED
--------------------------------------------------------- live log finish ---------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG 17:41:39: ReportPortal - Finish TestItem: request_body={'end_time': '1650555699144', 'status': 'PASSED', 'issue': None, 'item_id': '6647d85e-4c35-4798-acc5-17b18dcb5c48'}
DEBUG 17:41:39: ... "PUT /api/v2/testchuck/item/6647d85e-4c35-4798-acc5-17b18dcb5c48 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG 17:41:39: finish_test_item - ID: 6647d85e-4c35-4798-acc5-17b18dcb5c48
DEBUG 17:41:39: response message: Accepted finish request for test item ID = 6647d85e-4c35-4798-acc5-17b18dcb5c48
----------------------------------------------------- live log sessionfinish ------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG 17:41:39: ReportPortal - Finish launch: request_body={'end_time': '1650555699384'}
DEBUG 17:41:39: ... "PUT /api/v2/testchuck/launch/1c4b1457-4e0a-4804-8749-391f77899385/finish HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG 17:41:39: finish_launch - ID: 1c4b1457-4e0a-4804-8749-391f77899385
DEBUG 17:41:39: response message: <reportportal_client.static.defines._PresenceSentinel object at 0x7fcac9ed9cd0>
DEBUG 17:41:39: Waiting for worker <reportportal_client.core.worker.APIWorker object at 0x7fcac8e27550> to completeprocessing batches.
DEBUG 17:41:39: [APIWorker] Received {ControlCommand.STOP} command
DEBUG 17:41:39: [APIWorker] Processing {ControlCommand.STOP} command
DEBUG 17:41:39: [APIWorker] Exiting due to {ControlCommand.STOP} command
```

It seems that there is a problem with the logging that seems to be invoked by the web-driver.
What I don't understand is - why does the future_nonce terminate as 'done' when the log.debug messages begin - and only after the first debug message?

For the sake of what I need to do in the end - I do need to have the multi-threaded solution, where one thread serves the page, another thread operates selenium automation on the page. The code above is just a minimal implementation to reproduce the issue.

Could someone please help me in obtaining the same behavior (meaning: a complete execution of the page_worker, returning the page title), but with reportportal integration in this 'infrastructure' ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug inside Report Portal client which is fixed in version [5.2.2](https://github.com/reportportal/client-Python/releases/tag/5.2.2)
Please use the latest version of the client: https://pypi.org/project/reportportal-client/